# How were ZPM's Made?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

Is there any in universe explanation about how ZPM's were made?

Why could this process not be replicated by humans?

A quick read of this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_technology_in_Stargate#Zero_Point_Module) page brings up this information:

> A fictional Ancient power source used to power their cities and outposts. ZPMs supposedly extract vacuum energy from a small artificially-created region of subspace, based on the concept of zero-point energy. ZPMs are depicted as more powerful and efficient than fictional Naquadah generators or any conventional energy source on present day Earth, and are shown as lasting for thousands of years.

Comment: This almost certainly would have been an issue in later episodes of SG-1 or Atlantis had they not been canceled. The whole theme of the show was that, given enough time, Stargate Command always managed to figure out these technologies itself.

Comment: Even if we assume that the4 SGC learned **how** to make a ZPM, they also would have lacked the means. Lets say that you know how to make a nuclear reactor and you write down the process. If those notes are given to the Roman bronze smith of 117 BCE they'll still be unable to build one, even if they can read and understand what you've written.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [Stargate Wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Zero_Point_Module), no in universe explanation has ever been given to the construction method, but it does give this explanation:

> Although the Ancients and Asurans were able to produce ZPMs as needed, every ZPM discovered and used by the Tau'ri and Wraith has been obtained from either leftover Ancient technology and outposts or the Asuran homeworld. Since the knowledge behind their construction eludes both sides, their only option is to locate existing ones.

While I'm sure both species study the ZPM's religiously, the technology is still beyond both.

Answer (score 2):

There has been sort of an explanation how ZPMs made recently.

Essentially Joseph Mallozzi (writer of SGA & SG1) said that there is some sort of Pocket dimension where the ZPMs are made. Mostly for Safety reasons.

Comment: This answer could be improved by finding the original quote and transcribing it.

Comment: @Valorum I know i tried for a resonable amount of time to find the original interview but could not find it.

Answer (score -1):

I figured the secret to making ZPMs was in the Atlantis database, but it is massive and their best secrets are probably heavily encrypted.  Still, you’d think the SGC would send a dedicated team just to work on finding that data.

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is that the ZPM basically shunts entropy to the artificial region is was created for. So the module doesn't so much run out of charge as the artificial region reaches maximum entropy. This would seem to indicate that the ZPM's construction isn't like a conventional battery that has to be charged. My Theory is the difficulty in making a ZPM (based on their relative scarcity) is that it takes a long time to make the required calculation to carve out a region of artificial subspace. The process may even have diminishing returns, like calculating digits of PI. The first few are easy relative the  millionth is more difficult.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This doesn't really explain *how* they were made, and a lot of it seems to be your personal theory.  Can you point to any evidence in the show to demonstrate the process and techniques of creating a ZPM?

Comment: Well, ZPM's have always been Stargate's pen-ultimate MacGuffin's. To my knowledge there has never been any mention of either the facilities or the manufacturing methods, even in passing.